# Office 365 - Send alert notifications when there is a new device sign-in or multiple failed sign-in

Tags: security, azure-active-directory, office365

does anybody know if there is a way to send automatic alert notifications to Office 365 Users when there is a login in their accounts through a new device? Or when there are many failed login attempts?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Office 365 does not support the Login Notifications.

You can use [security policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/create-activity-alerts?view=o365-worldwide) or [MFA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-mfa-mfasettings) instead.

See a similar issue [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/office-365-login-notifications/c16b89c1-9df1-42df-ae91-7b1398ba01b3).

And you could vote up these User Voice Posts:

[Login Notifications](https://office365.uservoice.com/forums/273493-office-365-admin/suggestions/18894319-login-notifications)

[Alerts for when a user logs into another machine (login notifications)](https://office365.uservoice.com/forums/289138-office-365-security-compliance/suggestions/39630436-alerts-for-when-a-user-logs-into-another-machine)

[Login notification as an option instead of multi factor authentication](https://office365.uservoice.com/forums/264636-general/suggestions/18426226-login-notification-as-an-option-instead-of-multi-f)

[sign in notifications](https://office365.uservoice.com/forums/273493-office-365-admin/suggestions/40403176-sign-in-notifications)